# Did Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez or her office write and publish this FAQ concerning her Green New Deal?

Tags: united-states, politics

There is a PDF circulating online that is purported to be an FAQ released by Congresswoman Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez (hereinafter referred to as AOC).

[Here is a link to the PDF](https://apps.npr.org/documents/document.html?id=5729035-Green-New-Deal-FAQ)

Examples of high-profile claims that this was published by AOC:

- [Ben Shapiro criticizing the plan](https://www.dailywire.com/news/43194/aocs-green-new-deal-proposal-one-stupidest-ben-shapiro)
- [Many people on Twitter talking about it as excerpted in bizpacreview](https://www.bizpacreview.com/2019/02/07/how-is-the-document-real-details-of-aocs-green-new-deal-are-so-patently-absurd-its-actually-scary-721939)

Many other results in search engines talk about it.

There are two PDFs linked in the last article, one being the ["Resolution on a Green New Deal"](https://ocasio-cortez.house.gov/sites/ocasio-cortez.house.gov/files/Resolution%20on%20a%20Green%20New%20Deal.pdf) itself and the other purporting to be an FAQ about it.

Since the resolution is visible on the ocasio-cortez.house.gov website (as I've just linked to), I don't have any doubts as to its authenticity.

But the FAQ is another matter.  I did find an apparent link to the official site indexed in DuckDuckGo, as you can see here:

[image]

But [the page was taken down](https://ocasio-cortez.house.gov/media/blog-posts/green-new-deal-faq).  I found it on the WayBack machine, though: https://web.archive.org/web/20190207191119/https://ocasio-cortez.house.gov/media/blog-posts/green-new-deal-faq

But, this is only a blog post from the 5th of February, and doesn't match the text of the 7 Feb PDF I'm asking about which is the subject of so many tweets and articles.

**Is there any concrete evidence that this PDF came from AOC or her office as widely claimed in online media?**

A text version of the document can [also be found at NPR](https://apps.npr.org/documents/document.html?id=5729035-Green-New-Deal-FAQ).  I will quote a portion:

> LAUNCH: Thursday, February 7, at 8:30 AM.
>
> Overview
>
> We will begin work immediately on Green New Deal bills to put the
>   nuts and bolts on the plan described in this resolution (important to
>   say so someone else can’t claim this mantle).
>
> This is a massive transformation of our society with clear goals and
>   a timeline.
>
> - The Green New Deal resolution a 10-year plan to mobilize every aspect
>     of American society at a scale not seen since World War 2 to achieve
>     net-zero greenhouse gas emissions and create economic prosperity for
>     all.
>
> ...

The wording, particularly the parenthetical note, does not make sense as wording choices that would be used in an FAQ.  This, plus the absence of any indication on the document itself as to its authorship, is the reason for my skepticism over its origin.

There are also basic typographical errors, as for example the missing word "moon" here:

> ...
>
> Americans love a challenge. This is our moonshot.
>
> - When JFK said we’d go to the by the end of the decade, people said
>     impossible.
>
> ...

---

EDIT: To be clear, I am *not* asking about the draft resolution itself, which is quite obviously authentic and in addition is actually hosted on AOC's website.  I am only asking about the PDF which starts with the word "LAUNCH" and has "FAQ" in its name, and has nothing visible in the PDF which indicates who wrote it or even who is meant by "we" within the document.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you are skeptical about: is the origin of the document disputed by anyone? Otherwise what would you accept as a proof? We specifically do not accept questions like this, because... well in a week there will be way more evidence. I guess the question won't matter then.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the gist of the question. If  OP is not questioning the authenticity of the document, then it came from her or her office. Since her office works for her, and it's standard that elected representatives use their staff to do work on their behalf, does it matter whether it was her, or her office?  Or is the question whether it is an official communication on her behalf, at all?

Comment: Also, the file is linked by NPR which is reputable, and they [claim it's by AOC](https://www.npr.org/2019/02/07/691997301/rep-alexandria-ocasio-cortez-releases-green-new-deal-outline) so this question makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Sklivvz, the question title was altered.  The draft resolution is clearly authentic.  The FAQ PDF, which is what I actually linked to, is nowhere near as clear in its provenance, given the lack of any headers or footers or authorship information inline, and the basic typographical errors, and the fact that it wasn't present on AOC's website (unlike the draft resolution).  However, your point that NPR was given the file directly *by* AOC's office is a good one; I had missed that somehow.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, initially I thought the FAQ was a badly done summary document made by a third party, perhaps an opponent of AOC's, and only loosely based on her actual words and resolution.  This is not unheard of in U.S. politics; for example, the [fictitious 28th amendment proposal](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/28th-amendment/).  More generally, when a short, more digestible summary is made by a third party of an official document, *even when the summary is inaccurate,* I've seen commentators rely only on the summary and mistake it for an original (can't remember examples, sorry).

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought, initially, but the wording evolved. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Statements from ACO: https://twitter.com/AOC/status/1094331348813340672?s=20

Comment: So this question has boiled down to "Is there a version of HR109 on the internet which includes some notes that have spelling and grammar errors?"

Comment: Its the paying people “unwilling to work” and farting cows in the removed pre release FAQ that is the story. https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/news/congress/the-mysterious-case-of-aocs-scrubbed-green-new-deal-details

Comment: @DJClayworth It isn't trivial typos that is the issue so much as ambiguous claims on the part of AOC and unambiguous claims on the part of a staff worker that some of the more outlandish statements about e.g. paying people who were "unwilling to work" were never even in the draft but were fake news created by opponents. Either this is true or AOC (and staff) are being at best disingenuous about what the original draft contained. Either way, it seems like a reasonable question, so I am not sure why it is on hold.

Comment: You may think those are the story, but they are not actually in the question.Nor are they in the version linked to in the question.

Comment: @DJClayworth, both "unwilling to work" and "farting cows" are indeed in the version linked to in the question.  They are also in Ben Shapiro's article criticizing the plan, which is the first article I linked to as an example claim that the PDF came from AOC.  Daniel's comment is exactly correct.

Comment: @Sklivvz, it appears that this question matters *more* now than it did when I wrote it, since as Martin Schroder noted AOC herself has claimed there are doctored versions floating around.

Comment: The question **as written** does not matter at all. If you think it should be about specific claims made about the alleged draft then edit the question to include those claims, not a load of stuff about missing words in the FAQ.

Comment: Maybe you can use this as a source instead. Or it answers your question. [Ocasio-Cortez adviser admits he falsely claimed Green New Deal didn't promise security for those 'unwilling' to work'](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/ocasio-cortez-adviser-admits-he-falsely-claimed-green-new-deal-didnt-promise-security-for-those-unwilling-to-work)

Comment: For me, this question just has a ton going on. If you can edit down to one or two paragraphs, it helps with general understanding.

Comment: A short, left-slanted article that's also relevant: [Ocasio-Cortez Team Flubs a Green New Deal Summary, and Republicans Pounce](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/11/climate/green-new-deal-faq.html) Seems no one is left denying the claim, that there was a faq published by Ocasio-Cortez's staff that said things unrelated to climate change, like economic security "for all who are unable or unwilling to work."

Comment: @fredsbend It does seem that the express reason given for putting the question on hold ("there is insufficient data for a meaningful answer") no longer holds, if it ever did. It is sad that politically biased news organizations rather than a dispassionate stack exchange community would be the sources of meaningful answers. It is hard not to see an element of political censorship in the closing of the question, although I do agree that the question as worded is too verbose and needs editing.

Comment: @JohnColeman I invite you to edit it—I won’t have time in the next couple days.  I agree with your comment completely.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard The problem now is that if it is no longer disputed then it seems like it is off topic for another reason (unless part of the purpose of the site is to document past controversies). The question, while still interesting, has become somewhat moot.